# Is the following statement true? $(∀f(x) ∈ Y ∃! x ∈ X ⇔ ∀a,b ∈ X : f(a) = f(b) ⇒ a = b)$

Tags: propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Let $f: X → Y$, $x ↦ f(x)$ be a mapping and $X$ and $Y$ sets. As mentioned in the title, my question is, if therefore the following statement is true.

$$∀f(x) ∈ Y ∃! x ∈ X ⇔ ∀a,b ∈ X : f(a) = f(b) ⇒ a = b$$

That is, is $f$ injective, if and only if $∀f(x) ∈ Y ∃! x ∈ X$ is true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This $∀f(x)∈Y∃!x∈X$ is ill-formed. Do you mean ∀$y∈f(X)∃!x∈Xf(x)=y$?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for commenting. Yes, that is exactly what I mean. However, I don’t know why my initial statement is ill-formed.

Comment: It is ill-formed because in plain English it says "for all $f(x)$ there exists exactly one $x\in X$" . You wanted to say "for all $y$ in the range of $f$ there exists exactly one $x$ that is mapped to $y$ by $f$".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is the difference between saying „for all f(x) in Y there exists exactly one x in X“ and „for all y in the range of f there exists exactly one x, so that x is mapped to y by f“? Since all f(x) are elements of Y, but f(x) can‘t be any element in Y (just the ones that some x in X is mapped to) all f(x) ∈ Y should refer to the same objects as all y ∈ f(X). Since f(x) is per definition an element in Y that an x ∈ X is mapped to, you then wouldn‘t have to specify that this x is mapped to f(x). That is what I would have thought anyway.

Comment: Firstly there is always a well formed formula (wff) $\varphi$ after a quantifier, for example $\exists x\varphi$. After your $∃!x∈X$ there is no wff. Secondly something of the form $\forall x\in S\varphi$ is defined by $\forall x(x\in S\to\varphi)$. Unless you define $∀f(x)∈Y\varphi$ it is not a wff.